# term for strongly-connected-component with no outgoing edges

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a name for a component in the list of strongly-connected-components which has no outgoing edges?

For example, the single node in the lower right in the following graph.

[image]

(For example, in a Markov chain, this represents states with nonzero steady-state probabilities, although that's not the use case I'm looking for.)

Comment: A sink? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Not sure if there is a standard notation. Maybe *minimal absorbing subgraph* or *minimal sink*, i.e. it has zero out-degree but no proper subgraph has this propery which implies that it is strongly connected.

Answer (score 2):

In his book, *Social and Economic Networks*, Matthew Jackson refers to such component as strongly connected and closed:

> A *closed* set of agents is a $C \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that there is no directed link from an agent in $C$ to an agent outside of $C$ (that is, there is no pair $i \in C$ and $j \not\in C$ such that $T_{ij}>0$.

The terms *strongly connected* and *closed* appear together later to determine the convergence of Markov chains.